# Is it "God of" or "King of" [the UK]?

Tags: punctuation, british-english, scottish-english

I was going though this [oath](https://www.royal.uk/his-majesty-kings-oath-relating-security-church-scotland) :

> I, Charles the Third, by the Grace of God of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and of My other Realms and Territories, King, Defender of the Faith…

[image: Oath]

I think there is something wrong here (I am not sure: It may not be incorrect due to historical traditions or nonstandard punctuation or legal format or relic of some official text which must not be changed or some other general arbitrariness.)

The Punctuation (without a "Comma" after "God") will imply that there is the "God of the United Kingdom", which seems faulty.

With a comma (,) after "God", it will imply that Charles is the King of UK (by the Grace of God) which makes sense.

I wanted to ask the British & Scottish folks about this.
Is my interpretation correct? Is a comma not required?

Comment: As you've reformatted, the punctuation is that of 'stanza mode', where almost anything may be assumed at the end of a line. The original (linked to) _does_ have the problem you mention. It's in an archaic form, when, one assumes, punctuation was far less regimented. But anarthrous 'by the grace of God/Duke/Lord/Sheriff/Mayor ... of X' sounds suspect no matter how archaic the writing.

Comment: When I used the SO tool to "BlockQuote" that copy-paste text , that tool itself split the lines arbitrarily. Without adding new Punctuation , I split the lines a little more , which made it look like "stanza mode" ! Ok , I have removed all such artefacts & I have put in the whole text **"as-is"** , including a SnapShot. @EdwinAshworth

Comment: Why has this question got three downvotes? What's wrong with it? I suppose saying "by the grace of God **of** the United Kingdom” etc. is absurd but that's how it is written.

Answer (score 1):

It's the comma before *King* which is wrong. The [Royal Proclamation](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/39873/supplement/3023) made in May 1953 following the Royal Titles Act uses the form

> Elizabeth II, by the Grace of God of the
> United Kingdom of Great Britain and
> Northern Ireland and of Her other Realms
> and Territories Queen, Head of the
> Commonwealth, Defender of the Faith

The different phrases are expressed in an archaic order, but the second clause delimited by the first two commas is an idea complete in itself:

> Queen of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and of Her other Realms and Territories by the grace of God

The form says that she is Queen [of various places] by the grace of God, and that grace doesn't make her Head of the Commonwealth or Defender of the Faith.

The Gazette's search facility doesn't find many entries containing the words "Defender of the Faith", including that Royal Proclamation itself, so I don't know whether there's been another made by the new King. It's likely that there hasn't been: it took fifteen months from the late Queen's accession to her making her proclamation of titles and styles.

In the absence of a new proclamation, the old styles and titles are simply adjusted for the new King. It's not correct to separate the word *King* from the places of which the King is king.

Comment: I agree with your observation that the comma before King or Queen is wrong because the archaic order will move that King or Queen. That is wrong Punctuation in the Oath. Still, without the comma after God, "of God of the" sounds weird. I imagine that, when reading this aloud, there will be a Pause after God. In other words, there will be a Comma there.

Comment: ... of A B and C[,] King ... is so unusual an ordering in today's English that I'd say there aren't any absolute rules governing correct/incorrect punctuation.

Comment: *I am of these places king by the grace of god...* No commas there or when back in its odder inversion: *I am by the grace of god of these places king...*

Comment: This answer is entirely about the comma before *King* and does not address what the question is about: there being no comma after *God*. The answer does seem to imply that the absence of the comma there is OK, but if that is intended to be the answer, it should be made explicit. (One should bear in mind that there are three logically possible answers here: a comma is required, a comma is optional, a comma would be wrong. Whichever one thinks is the correct answer, one needs to rule out both of the other ones.)

Comment: Yes , that is Correct : My Question Post is on the three Possibilities & It is Premised on the "Comma is required" Possibility , @jsw29 , though I wonder how it could have escaped royal scrutiny !

Comment: And my answer says that your premise is not correct. It's a different comma which is wrong.